# How to clone a particular branch from Google CLoud Source Repository

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-source-repos

I am trying to clone a particular branch from Google Cloud Source Repository.

```
gcloud source repos clone <Repos_Name>
```

This command only scans the master branch not the dev branch that I am looking for

How to clone the particular brach?

Comment: Do you have tryed git clone ?ssh://[EMAIL]@source.developers.google.com:2022/p/[PROJECT_ID]/r/[REPO_NAME] 

See more in doc https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/cloning-repositories#gcloud

Comment: You can't clone a particular branch, only a repository and then switch to a branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. clone your repo

   gcloud source repos clone <Repos_Name>

2.fetch remote branch

```
git fetch --all
```

3.checkout your desire branch

```
git checkout ＜remotebranch＞
```